# What are the proper labels for these wires in this AC power cord?

Tags: power, ac, wiring, cables

I am trying to wire this AC power cord to a 5V 20A power supply, but it appears to have non-standard coloring. From what I've read, blue is ground, white will go to neutral, and brown will go to L, correct? This is the view with the female connector facing the camera.[image]

Comment: Color coding is not global. Call an electrician if you are in doubt.

Comment: What country is the cordset from?  That would be a hint.  In modern cordsets, blue is earth and brown is line, but the protective ground would be green and yellow

Comment: I bought it at a Micro Center in the US, but the cord itself was made in china, kingwin brand.

Comment: I've never heard of ANYONE using blue for protective ground ... I'd look at the circuit where the cord enters the power supply , rather than guess.

Comment: I'm looking at the female end. If the wires align with the holes, blue would be earth, white would be line, and brown would be neutral? Is there a way to check it besides looking at it?

Comment: I have no idea how to split the female end open to check besides brute force with a knife or melting with a lighter...

Comment: Use a multimeter to check continuity between the connector pins/holes and the wires.  (and strip the black outer sheath back a bit, so you can see the more of the insulation on the wires.)

Comment: How do I do this??

Comment: You put one meter lead in one of the holes in the connector, then test the bare wires for continuity to that pin. Repeat for each hole/pin.

Answer (score 4):

This is country specific and standards specific

GREEN is universally accepted to be a protective earth connection

White, Blue, Brown... is odd... if it wasn't for the white it would make sense.

[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_wiring

Comment: The 'white' might just be a pale green (the picture is ambiguous).

Comment: very true and then it would all make sense

Answer (score 0):

Don't go for colours . All the three wires having same characteristics . Check the source which pin is phase, neutral and earth . Connect the wire colour of ur choice and label it in the cabinet to help for future and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

The US/Canada standard is black=hot, white=neutral and ground is green, green-with-yellow-stripe or bare. The only other colours I've encountered is the standard I believe is UK/EU in which brown=hot, blue=neutral and ground is green with a yellow stripe. A lot of Chinese-made cables follow the EU standard.

Even with standard colours, I always check continuity with the plug pins to make sure it's right.

Your cable is very odd, in that it has no green (or bare or green/yellow) wire, and has white in combination with blue and brown. This is not anyone's standard for line voltage (120 or 240 Volts AC) cabling.

You should consider that this cable might not be intended for line voltage, even if Kingwin has molded an AC plug onto it. It may be intended for low-voltage DC in some specialty application, maybe low power lighting or communications. Look for printed specs on the sheath of the cable itself; it should say it's rated to some AC voltage higher than 120. If it doesn't, you might consider removing and discarding the AC plug and putting the cable in your parts bin for some future low-voltage project.

If it does appear to be an AC cable, then we have to assume that the folks at Kingwin used whatever colours they had handy. Make no assumptions on how this is wired; check it several times for continuity, preferably once before you have a coffee and once after.

When you're sure it's right, use electrical tape to mark the wires with the colours that will make sense to the next person that sees it. In the US that'd be black, white and green.